# How to show all the threads or instances of excel file in vb dot net.I want to show all the threads and one main process of excel files

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I show all the threads or instances of Excel file in vb dot net?

I want to show all the threads and one main process of Excel files. I have seen the process and process id but not a way to  show all threads of Excel, meaning if I open three Excel files I can show three files in listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an easy way to do this. Here is some code that I have modified from a similar situation. Firstly here is a class that gets the child window titles from a specified process id:

```vb
Class ChildWindowManager
    Delegate Function EnumThreadDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(ByVal dwThreadId As Integer, ByVal lpfn As EnumThreadDelegate, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Shared Function EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(ByVal processId As Integer) As List(Of IntPtr)
        Dim windowHandles = New List(Of IntPtr)()

        For Each thread As ProcessThread In Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads
            EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, Function(hWnd, lParam)
                                             windowHandles.Add(hWnd)
                                             Return True
                                         End Function, IntPtr.Zero)
        Next

        Return windowHandles
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetWindowTitle(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As String
        Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
        If length = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Dim titleStringBuilder As New Text.StringBuilder("", length)

        GetWindowText(hWnd, titleStringBuilder, titleStringBuilder.Capacity + 1)
        Return titleStringBuilder.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetChildWindowTitles(processId As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim windowTitles As New List(Of String)

        For Each handle In EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(processId)
            Dim windowText = GetWindowTitle(handle)
            If windowText <> Nothing Then
                windowTitles.Add(windowText)
            End If
        Next

        Return windowTitles
    End Function

End Class
```

The class works by using the `EnumThreadWindows` function to get a list of the handles of child windows and then uses `GetWindowTextLength` and `GetWindowText` to get the actual title of those child windows (if they have one).

Here is a simple console app showing how to use the class:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Sub Main()
    Dim allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(p) p.ProcessName.Contains("EXCEL"))
    Dim windowTitles = ChildWindowManager.GetChildWindowTitles(allProcesses.First().Id)

    For Each title In windowTitles
        If (title.Contains("- Excel")) Then
            Console.WriteLine(title)
        End If
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This code gets the processes that contain the name EXCEL. There is normally only one of these. It then uses that get all the child windows that have the text '- Excel' in them. This should give you the list you require.