# How to get all instances of WINWORD Process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, wmi, managementeventwatcher

I want to get all the instances of WINWORD processes. As shown in image i have running two windows in WINWORD process. I want to get their file name and path.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
 Dim processStartEvent As ManagementEventWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace")
    Dim processStopEvent As ManagementEventWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler processStartEvent.EventArrived, AddressOf Me.processStartEvent_EventArrived
        processStartEvent.Start()
        AddHandler processStopEvent.EventArrived, AddressOf Me.processStopEvent_EventArrived
        processStopEvent.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub processStartEvent_EventArrived(EventArrivedEventArgs, e)
        Dim processName As String = e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString
        Dim processID As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value).ToString
        FileIO.WriteToFile("+ Process started. Name: " & processName & " | ID: " + processID)
        FileIO.WriteToFile(" | Date & Time: ")
        FileIO.WriteToFile(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub processStopEvent_EventArrived(EventArrivedEventArgs, e)
        Dim processName As String = e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value.ToString
        Dim processID As String = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessID").Value).ToString
        FileIO.WriteToFile("- Process stopped. Name: " & processName & " | ID: " + processID)
        FileIO.WriteToFile(" | Date & Time: ")
        FileIO.WriteToFile(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    End Sub
```

I am getting Process name , ID and Date and Time of a Process. I want to get instances of a Processes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netframework-4.8?

Comment: That is a single process 'winword' with multiple child windows. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355374/how-to-show-all-the-threads-or-instances-of-excel-file-in-vb-dot-net-i-want-to-s/57356504#57356504) is a way to get the window titles from each child window. This allows you to see the name of the document being edited. (References Excel but the concept is the same for Word).

Comment: You can see that its a single process if you use the Task Manager. Right click on the columns and select PID. You will see Word has a single Process ID.

Comment: see the code below @theduck

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code for Word Instances but it is doing nothing for me.

Public Class MyNewService
    Dim tmr As Timers.Timer

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Try
        Dim allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().Where(Function(p) p.ProcessName.Contains("WINWORD.EXE"))
        Dim windowTitles = ChildWindowManager.GetChildWindowTitles(allProcesses.First().Id)
        For Each title In windowTitles
            If (title.Contains("- Word")) Then
                FileIO.WriteToFile(title)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Class ChildWindowManager

    Delegate Function EnumThreadDelegate(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(ByVal dwThreadId As Integer, ByVal lpfn As EnumThreadDelegate, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Shared Function EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(ByVal processId As Integer) As List(Of IntPtr)
        Dim windowHandles = New List(Of IntPtr)()

        For Each thread As ProcessThread In Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads
            EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, Function(hWnd, lParam)
                                             windowHandles.Add(hWnd)
                                             Return True
                                         End Function, IntPtr.Zero)
        Next
        Return windowHandles
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetWindowTitle(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As String
        Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
        If length = 0 Then Return Nothing

        Dim titleStringBuilder As New Text.StringBuilder("", length)

        GetWindowText(hWnd, titleStringBuilder, titleStringBuilder.Capacity + 1)
        Return titleStringBuilder.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetChildWindowTitles(processId As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim windowTitles As New List(Of String)
        For Each handlee In EnumerateProcessWindowHandles(processId)
            Dim windowText = GetWindowTitle(handlee)
            If windowText <> Nothing Then
                windowTitles.Add(windowText)
            End If
        Next

        Return windowTitles
    End Function

End Class

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
    tmr = New Timers.Timer()
    tmr.Enabled = True
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Service is Started!" + vbNewLine)
    FileIO.WriteToFile(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    tmr.Enabled = False
    FileIO.WriteToFile(vbNewLine)
    FileIO.WriteToFile("Service is Stopped!" + vbNewLine)
    FileIO.WriteToFile(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Think you should post this as a new question as it doesn't answer your original question. However, for me the ProcessName for Word instances is `WINWORD` not `WINWORD.EXE` so your code will never find the correct instances. If you remove the try/catch it would probably just throw that error and make debugging easier. Changing WINWORD.EXE to WINWORD made your code work for me.

Comment: Getting 0 output

Comment: if i remove try catch i got error while i start service the error is : Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: I am using try and catch to run my service. But unfortunately i am getting nothing zero output.

Comment: I have tried your code in Console Application. Same there no output.

Comment: In your console app - can you see `allProcesses` has 1 process in it? (Assuming you have changed WINWORD.EXE to WINWORD and you have at least one copy of Word running.

Comment: Yes i got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It shows me the word application file names which were opened before starting the application. What should i do to show the files which i open after at the run time.

Comment: Actually i am working on window services, I want to monitor word processes which includes document file name , starting and stopping time.

Comment: You will need to run the same code on a timer and re-scan the system on some interval.